# C# XmlSerialiser to Oracle Clob optimization

Tags: c#, oracle, stream

I go through many steps in order to save an xml file to an Oracle database.

```
XmlCustomType xmlCustomType = new XmlCustomType();

// feed xmlCustomType

var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlCustomType));

string xml;

using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, xmlCustomType);
    xml = textWriter.ToString();

    using (var sr = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        char[] buffer = new char[1000];
        int numChars;

        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(""))
        {
            OracleClob clob = new OracleClob(con);

            while ((numChars = sr.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                clob.Write(buffer, 0, numChars);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to optimize this with something like

```
XmlCustomType xmlCustomType = new XmlCustomType();

// feed xmlCustomType

var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlCustomType));

using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(""))
{
    OracleClob clob = new OracleClob(con);
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(clob, xmlCustomType);
}
```

Unfortunatly I Get this error message that I cannot undestand :

> Operations on the Unicode byte arrays require that some parameters have even values

What would be the minimal steps to go from xmlserializer to OracleClob ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing from 1000 to 100000 buffer size speed up the process a lot.

Each clob.write is a request to database, so by doing that it lowers number of request to database.